# SSIS Package Validation Error email task when attaching file created by previous task

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

While running in debug mode an SSIS package I get the folowing error. 
"file ... does not exist ...",  but the file is created by a task earlier in the process, so most probably it will exist at runtime but not at validation. How to deal with this ?

```
Package Validation Error
------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Error at Send Zip file [Send Mail Task]: Either the file "..." does not exist or you do not have permissions to access the file.

Error at Send Zip file: There were errors during task validation.

 (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls make sure you have tried the solutions below

- Set DelayValidation property set to True for the Send Mail Task.
- Close the filestream of the log file before sending the email

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked with first option, DelayValidation = True on Send Mail Task.

Comment: @user3752281 awesome !! :)